# Regular expression matching using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have created a shell script below that checks whether the file out.txt contains any line with the text "Billing_20160210". I am getting the error in the regular expression part which states that "[[: not found". Not sure whether i am missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
bq ls test:Dataset_test > out.txt
cat out.txt | while read LINE
do 
  if [ LINE = *"Billing_20160210"* ]; 
  then 
    echo "Processing $LINE"
  fi
done
```

Edit not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
bq ls geotab-bigdata-test:JS_test > out.txt
cat out.txt | while read LINE
do 
 if [[ $LINE == *"DailyBillingTest_20160210"* ]];
 then 
  echo "Processing $LINE"
 fi
done
```

Comment: There is no regex here just glob. Replace`[ LINE = *"Billing_20160210"* ]` with `[[ $LINE == *"Billing_20160210"* ]]`

Comment: This is also a case of UUOC

Comment: `[[: not found` also implies that you aren't actually using bash as your interpreter to run this script. Are you invoking it with `sh yourscript`? If so, that would override the `#!/bin/bash` shebang. If invoking with an explicit interpreter, that needs to be `bash yourscript`, not `sh yourscript`.

Comment: What exactly is that "Change:" edit? Is that saying that this is what you've also tried that's having the same effect? That this is your proposed solution? (If so, solutions should be in answers, not edits to questions; it's acceptable to add an answer to your own question, though polite to encourage someone whose comment helped you to put that comment in an answer themselves).

Comment: @anubhava: I have replaced that line. Even then I am getting the error "[[: not found". I am using gedit editor and run the script using sh test.sh.

Comment: I've already described why `sh test.sh` is wrong.

Comment: Give the script execution permission and run it properly:
chmod +x script.sh && ./script.sh

Comment: (...btw, filename extensions on scripts are bad form -- a `.sh` extension falsely implies that `sh` can be used to run a script, which is simply untrue if it's a bash script [hence your bug here], and using an extension at all means you need to either change your callers to invoke the script differently or have its name be inaccurate if you rewrite it in a different language. You don't run `ls.elf`; why would you use extensions on other commands you write yourself?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a shell loop to filter a file line by line. Use `grep` as a filter here:

```
grep 'Billing_20160210' out.txt | while read -r line ; do
    echo "processing ${line}"
done
```

Or even without a temporary file:

```
bq ls test:Dataset_test | grep 'Billing_20160210' | while read -r line ; do
    echo "processing ${line}"
done
```

Comment: Granted, moving to this (POSIX-compliant) code moots the issue, but it might not hurt to *also* address interpreter selection, as that was the most immediate fault. Surely the OP will also write bash-specific code on other occasions in their future; understanding why one can't use `sh` to run a `bash` script thus has utility beyond this single immediate question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thank you. It works. This is the first time i am trying to run a shell script, so did not get that point in the beginning.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see your point. If a file extension is desired it should be `.bash`.. I'm also used to `.sh` but I admit that it is not correct as long as the code isn't 100% POSIX compliant.

Comment: *nod*. The approach I tend to encourage is to use an extension reflecting the minimum compatible shell (.sh for POSIX, .bash/.ksh/.zsh etc if appropriate) if a script is intended to be sourced, or leave it off if it's only expected to be executed -- if being sourced, the interpreter to be used is information the user needs to have available, and it's consistent with standard behavior in other languages (ie. Python modules end in .py, Python executable entrypoints generated with setuptools etc don't).